# HttpMessageHandler vs DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

`DelegatingHandler` herda de `HttpMessageHandler`. Mas não entendi a diferença, dado que é necessário implementar o mesmo método: `SendAsync`, para realizar a mesma operação.

Qual a diferença entre estes dois `Handlers`? Quando se deve usar um ou outro? O que um faz o outro também faz?